# How to fix Unknown column in 'field list' ERROR Glassfish server

Tags: java, database, jpa, glassfish, jpql

can you guys see what's wrong with my code, I'm trying to persist manager data to database, however, it said: Unknown column 'EMAIL' in 'field list'.

ERROR:

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception
> [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
> 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
> Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'EMAIL' in
> 'field list' Error Code: 1054 Call: INSERT INTO MANAGER (ID, EMAIL,
> FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PHONENUMBER) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  bind => [5
> parameters bound] Query: InsertObjectQuery(manager.Manager@1d0494b4)
> at
> org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl$1.handleException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:772)
> at
> org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.handleException(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:275)
> at
> org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:170)
> at
> org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
> ... 65 more

Manager.java

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name= "viewManager", query ="select m from Manager m where m.id = :id"),
@NamedQuery(name= "findManager", query ="select m from Manager m where m.firstName = :firstName and m.lastName = :lastName"),
@NamedQuery(name= "findAllManager", query ="select m from Manager m"),
})
public class Manager implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="manerger_fk")
    private List<Allocation> allocation;

    public Manager() {
    }

    public Manager( String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String email, List<Allocation> allocation) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
        this.allocation = allocation;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Allocation> getAllocation() {
        return allocation;
    }

    public void setAllocation(List<Allocation> allocation) {
        this.allocation = allocation;
    }
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    
}
```

I also add `@Column(name="accountid", nullable = false, unique = true)` but it seems no use.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
I change the schema generation in persistence.xml from "create" to "drop-and-create" and it works.